# Yii Upload Image to Database

Tags: php, image, yii, image-upload

Ive been trying to upload an image file into my data base which as the attribute image_name.  I want to be able to store the image and then store its file path into my database.. Ive tried many options on here.. but can't seem to figure out how to do it...

This is what I've got so far if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great...

Thanks

Model -

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'movie_name' => 'Movie Name',
        'studio_id' => 'Studio',
        'country_id' => 'Country',
        'movie_rating_id' => 'Movie Rating',
        'map_pin_id' => 'Map Pin',
        'description' => 'Description',
        'title_image' => 'Title Image',
        'title_trailer_youtube_code' => 'Title Trailer Youtube Code',
        'release_date' => 'Release Date',
        'bg_colour_code' => 'Bg Colour Code',
        'text_colour_code' => 'Text Colour Code',
        'is_released' => 'Is Released',
        'is_advanced_booking_allowed' => 'Is Advanced Booking Allowed',
        'advanced_booking_start_date' => 'Advanced Booking Start Date',
        'advanced_booking_end_date' => 'Advanced Booking End Date',
        'domain_prefix' => 'Domain Prefix',
        'facebook_app_id' => 'Facebook App',
        'facebook_app_url' => 'Facebook App Url',
        'facebook_icon_image_url' => 'Facebook Icon Image Url',
        'facebook_text' => 'Facebook Text',
        'twitter_text' => 'Twitter Text',
        'booking_share_text' => 'Booking Share Text',
        'home_tracking_url' => 'Home Tracking Url',
        'shows_tracking_url' => 'Shows Tracking Url',
    );
}
```

Controller -

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Movie;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Movie']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Movie'];
        $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'title_image');
        $fileName = $uploadedFile;
        $model->title_image = $fileName;
        if($model->save())
            $uploadedFile->saveAs('http://localhost:8888/MY/Movies/title_image/'.$fileName);
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Your question does not give out any information at all. What is the problem? What happens?

Comment: it does not seem to create a new record in the database and doesn't store the image file path or the image in its location..

Comment: Reading the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile) will probably help: "Call `getInstance` to retrieve the instance of an uploaded file, and then use `saveAs` to save it on the server."

Comment: Ive looked at this and my code seems correct.. just can't seem to get to the bottom of it...

Comment: The classic enctype="multipart/form-data" on your form tag perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code, `uploadedFile->saveAs()` method expect full path to the file, not url.

To get full path, try with this:

```
$uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/images/uploaded/'.$fileName);
```

In this example `images` dir should be at same level as `protected` dir (only if `images` dir is being used for display public images through url):

```
assets/
images/
protected/
themes/
```

If you are on Unix environment, make sure to give proper read/write access to `images` dir.

If doesn't work, [review this useful sample tutorial step by step](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/) that helps to introduce to file uploading with Yii.